# React Native: mobile number validation accept numeric value only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

How validate mobile number in react native accept the only numeric value.

```
 <TextInput
      ref='mobileNo'
      keyboardType="numeric"
      style={[styles.textInput, { width: '100%' }]}
      placeholder='Enter mobile number'
      onChangeText={(value) => this.handleChange('mobileNo', value)}   />
```

I have used `keyboardType="numeric"` but its accept special character also so I want to accept the only numeric value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check if input string is number or not. Check below code:

```
 <TextInput
   ref='mobileNo'
   keyboardType="numeric"
   style={[styles.textInput, { width: '100%' }]}
   placeholder='Enter mobile number'
   onChangeText={(value) => 
   let num = value.replace(".", '');
     if(isNaN(num)){
         // Its not a number
     }else{
        this.handleChange('mobileNo', num)}  
     }
 />
```

Comment: i do same thing but if i enter the 9852336.25 accept as numeric value but they not valid number format.

Comment: You can replace . with blank value. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Use this validation.**

```
mobilevalidate(text) {
    const reg = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/;
    if (reg.test(text) === false) {
      this.setState({
        mobilevalidate: false,
        telephone: text,
      });
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        mobilevalidate: true,
        telephone: text,
        message: '',
      });
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Adding required digits in [789] group if required

Answer (score 6):

Try using `keyboardType='phone-pad'`.

Comment: This will still allow the user to enter non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this and you don't have to use if or any other statement...

First of all download this package to your root folder, this is a inbuild package of [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-validator-form) to download type this command in your cmd prompt....

```
npm i react-native-validator-form
```

Then import it to your project.

```
import { Form, TextValidator } from 'react-native-validator-form';
```

Then create a class and extend it with [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and copy-paste the following code...

```
state = {
    phonenumber: ''
  }

handleSubmit = () => {
   this.refs.form.submit();
}
render() {
    const {phonenumber} = this.state;
    return (
        <Form 
            ref="form"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        > 
          <TextValidator
            name="phonenumber"
            validators={['required', 'isNumber','maxNumber:11']}
            errorMessages={['Phonenumber is required', 'Phonenumber invalid' , 'Not a valid number ']}
            placeholder="Phonenumber"
            value={phonenumber}
            onChangeText={(phonenumber) => this.setState({phonenumber})}
        />
           <Button
                title="Submit"
                onPress={this.handleSubmit}
            />
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to check in the onChangeText handler which input was typed and to issue an error if the user entered a non-numeric character.

If the field is a controlled component (its value is set from a state variable, and the state variable is being set in the onChangeText handler), you can not accept the invalid character at all (so that the user types, for example, a '.', and it is not dven displayed).

Whether you explain to the user why his input is not accepted is up to you (either by writing it in the field's label, e.g. "phone number(digits only), or in a string below the field, or by displaying an error).